# Anchor tag background image doesn't show

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of code:

```
<div id="button-wrapper">
    <a id="matematica"></a><br>
    <a id="romana">s</a><br>
    <a id="informatica">s</a><br>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#matematica {
background-image:url('profile.jpg');
}
```

I don't know why the mentioned background image doesn't appear! I also tried setting the width and height of the anchor tag, still nothing.

Comment: `a` is an `inline` DOM element change it to `display: inline-block` or `block`   for using bg-image.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to display it as `block`/`inline-block` and then apply your width and height.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1w29pbpf/

Comment: I am using `inline-block` in my website's design for a (new) button element I'm designing which is an `a`; however, even when it's an `inline-block`, my image does not appear.